# Conditional ListPlot with text recognition

Tags: plotting

This is my data

```
mydata = {{0.55, 31.7, 26.360, "acid 0-TOLUIC"}, {0.3925, 31.503, 
31.4861, "acid 2- methyloctanoic"}, {0.711, 11.299, 17.4735, 
"acid 6-hydroxyhexanoic"}, {0.495, 27.57, 30.437, 
"acid acetic"}, {0.506, 49.6, 35.486, 
"acid acetoxyacetic"}, {0.753, 17.37, 13.3028, 
"acid acetylsalicylic"}, {0.873, 5.576, 5.325, 
"acid azelaic"}, {0.652, 17.968, 17.040, 
"acid cyclopentylacetic"}, {0.471, 33.9659, 33.384, 
"acid glutaric"}, {0.753, 26.96, 20.881, 
"acid isophtalic"}, {0.673, 22.433, 26.411, 
"acid maleic"}, {0.627, 25.7, 21.504, "acid m-toluic"}, {0.749, 
12.187, 10.113, "acid neohexanoic"}, {0.5512, 20.3642, 22.555, 
"acid n-nonanoic"}, {0.802, 7.629, 8.243, 
"acid n-undecanoic"}, {0.830, 9.426, 10.141, 
"acid phtalic"}, {0.864, 8.713, 7.9158, "acid salycilic"}};
```

I want to plot the data with different colors depending to name of the data.
So, if the data are (e.g. "acid n-undecanoic" or "acid salycilic") in a particular way I want them in red otherwise in green.
Following my not working code.

```
ListPlot[{mydata[[All, 2]], mydata[[All, 1]]}\[Transpose], 
PlotStyle -> {If[
mydata[[All, -1]] == "acid n-undecanoic" || 
mydata[[All, -1]] == "acid salycilic", Red, Green]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ListPlot[List /@ mydata[[;; , {2, 1}]], BaseStyle -> PointSize@.02, PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotStyle -> Replace[mydata[[;; , -1]], 
                      {"acid n-undecanoic" | "acid salycilic" -> Red, _ -> Green},
                      {1}]
 ]
```

Comment: So it is just plotting not one set of points but many 1-point sets.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple step-by-step approach.

```
sorted = Sort @ mydata;
pts = List /@ sorted[[All, ;; 2]];
colors = 
  If[StringMatchQ[#, "acid n-undecanoic" | "acid salycilic"], Red, Green] & /@ 
    sorted[[All, -1]];
ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> colors]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

The above plot would really be more useful if it had tooltips identifying which acid a point represented on mouse-over. Such tooltips are really easy to add. Here is  the code showing how to add them:

```
Module[{sorted, pts, names, colors},
  sorted = Sort @ myData;
  pts = List /@ sorted[[All, ;; 2]];
  names = sorted[[All, -1]];
  colors = 
    If[StringMatchQ[#, "acid n-undecanoic" | "acid salycilic"], Red, Green] & /@ names;
  ListPlot[Thread[Tooltip[pts, names]], PlotStyle -> colors]]
```

[image: tooltips]

Comment: Very smart solution...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative using `Graphics`

```
acids[data_, choice_] := Module[{points},

  points =
   data /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :>
     If[Or @@ choice /. s_String :> d == s,
      {Text[d, {b, a - 0.025}], {Red, Point[{b, a}]}},
      {Blue, Point[{b, a}]}];

  Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], points},
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
   Axes -> True,
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0.3},
   ImageSize -> 400]]

acids[mydata, {"acid glutaric", "acid acetic", "acid azelaic"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is `Style`ing individual points in the data set and using the styled data set as the input to `ListPlot`. Define a coloring function:

```
colorF["acid n-undecanoic" | "acid salycilic"] = Red;
colorF[_] := Green;

styleddata = Style[{#2, #1}, colorF[#4], PointSize@.02] & @@@ mydata;
ListPlot[styleddata]
```

[image]

Note: We can also use `colorF` to set the option value for `PlotStyle` after breaking `mydata` into `Length[mydata]` data sets as in Kuba's approach:

```
ListPlot[List /@ mydata[[All, {2, 1}]], 
         BaseStyle -> PointSize@.02, 
         PlotStyle -> (colorF /@ mydata[[All, -1]])]
```

[image]

Since we do not break the data into individual points or change the ordering of points in the data set while styling, we can use the option `Joined -> True` directly, when we need to, without additional processing:

```
ListPlot[styleddata, Joined->True, PlotMarkers->{Automatic, 0}]
```

[image]

**Update:**  A function similar to `colorF` can be used for labeling select points (Thanks @eldo for raising the bar:)

```
labelF[a : "acid n-undecanoic" | "acid salycilic"] := a;
labelF[_] := "";
styleddata = Style[Labeled[{#2, #1}, labelF@#4, Below], colorF@#4, PointSize@.02] & @@@ mydata;
ListPlot[styleddata]
```

[image]

Comment: That's exceptional!